# sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unknown option to `s'

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use sed to update a config file using a bash script. I have a similar sed command right above this one in the script that runs fine. I can't seem to figure out why this is breaking:

```
sed -i.bak \
    -e s/"socketPath:'https://localhost:9091'"/"socketPath:'/socket'"/g \
    $WEB_CONF
```

Any ideas?

Comment: an alternative fix is to escape the slashes i.e. https:\/\/localhost:9091

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The quotes and double quotes are causing problems.
You are using them in view of the slashes in the string.
In sed you can use another delimiter, such as a #.

```
sed -e 's#socketPath:https://localhost:9091#socketPath:/socket#g' \
$WEB_CONF
```

Answer (score 8):

Escape your slashes in the pattern or use a different delimiter like this:

```
sed -i.bak \
-e s%"socketPath:'https://localhost:9091'"%"socketPath:'/socket'"%g \
$WEB_CONF
```

Answer (score 3):

I am confused looking at the delimiters you have used so you can't blame `sed` for goofing up. When your dataset has `/` in them, it is often advised to use a different delimiters like `#` or `_` (yes, `sed` supports various delimiters).

Also, your quoting looks abit off. The syntax should be:

```
sed -i.bak 's#substitute#replacement#g' "$WEB_CONF"
```

If your substitute and/or replacement has variables use `"` instead `'` which will allow it to interpolate.