# Use a variable as replacement in bash sed command

Tags: bash, sed

I am using the `sed` command on Ubuntu to replace content.

This initial command comes from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412835/append-text-with-echo-without-new-line).

```
sed -i '$ s/$/ /replacement/' "$DIR./result/doc.md"
```

However, as you can see, I have a slash in the replacement. The slash causes the command to throw:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'

Moreover, my replacement is stored in a variable.

So the following **will not** work because of the slash:

```
sed -i "$ s/$/ $1/" "$DIR./result/doc.md"
```

As stated [here and in duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182050/sed-e-expression-1-char-23-unknown-option-to-s), I should use another delimiter. If I try with `@`:

```
   sed -i "$ s@$@ $1@" "$DIR./result/doc.md"
```

It gives the error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 42: unterminated `s' command

My question is:

**How can I use a variable in this command as well as other delimiter than `/` ?**

Comment: `$@` has a meaning in bash. Use something else as the delimiter, or use e.g. Perl that comes with real variables instead of the shell's macro expansions.

Comment: You just picked a bad delimiter. `@` is a shell parameter, so `$@` inside double quotes is expanded. Build the `sed` script using a combination of  single-quoted and double-quoted strings, or pick a different delimiter. Keep in mind, though, that without extra care, any value of `$1` could break the script.

Comment: Unrelated, consider using `ed` rather than `sed -i`.

Comment: @chepner using underscore (`sed -i "$ s_$_ $1_" "$DIR./result/doc.md"` gives the same error: sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unterminated `s' command

Comment: `_` is *also* a shell parameter :) Try `|`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed)

Comment: You can also escape the `$` in the script to avoid unintended parameter expansion regardless of your chosen delimiter: `"\$ s@\$@ $1@"`, for example.

Comment: @chepner Damn me ! Works like a charm now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR:

Try:

```
sed -i '$ s@$@ '"$1"'@' "$DIR./result/doc.md"
```

Long version:

Let's start with your original code:

```
sed -i '$ s/$/ /replacement/' "$DIR./result/doc.md"
```

And let's compare it to the code you referenced:

```
sed -i '$ s/$/abc/' file.txt
```

We can see that they don't exactly match up.  I see that you've correctly made this substitution:

```
file.txt --> "$DIR./result/doc.md"
```

That looks fine (although I do have my doubts about the . after $DIR ).  However, the other substitution doesn't look great:

```
abc -->  /replacement
```

You actually introduced another delimeter /.   However, if we replace the delimiters with '@' we get this:

```
sed -i '$ s@$@ /replacement@' "$DIR./result/doc.md"
```

I think that the above is perfectly valid in sed/bash.  The `$@` will not be replaced by the shell because it is single quoted.  The `$DIR` variable *will* be interpolated by the shell because it is double quoted.

Looking at one of your attempts:

```
sed -i "$ s@$@ $1@" "$DIR./result/doc.md"
```

You will have problems due to the shell interpolation of $@ in the double quotes.  Let's correct that by replacing with single quotes (but leaving $1 unquoted):

```
sed -i '$ s@$@ '"$1"'@' "$DIR./result/doc.md"
```

Notice the '"$1"'.  I had to surround $1 with '' to basically unescape the surrounding single quotes.  But then I surrounded the $1 with double quotes so we could protect the string from white spaces.

Comment: I tested it and it works. However I prefere the solution that has been provided to me in comments. This solution is just "replacing delimiters with pipes". `sed -i "$ s|$| $1|" "$DIR./result/doc.md"`

Comment: @FlorianCastelain, that only works until your input or output data has a pipe in it; it's not a complete and robust solution. Try where `$1` contains `'foo|bar|baz'`.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain:  I do not like @ as a delimeter either.  I typically use colon `:` when forward slash `/` becomes unwieldy.  My point in answering is to illustrate how proper quoting can avoid the shell interpolation for $@.  Meanwhile, quoting is flexible enough to indicate where you  require interpolation.  Nonetheless, I can't refute Charles' argument that a delimiter character in your `$1` variable will break your sed script.  You can probably defend against it  by searching $1 for characters that will break your script or going with  approaches shared by Charles.

Answer (score 1):

## Don't use `sed` here; `perl` and `awk` allow more robust approaches.

`sed` doesn't allow variables to be passed out-of-band from code, so they always need to be escaped. Use a language without that limitation, and you have code that always works, no matter what characters your data contains.

### The Short Answer: Using `perl`

The below is taken from [BashFAQ #21](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021#How_can_I_replace_a_string_with_another_string_in_a_variable.2C_a_stream.2C_a_file.2C_or_in_all_the_files_in_a_directory.3F):

```
inplace_replace() {
  local search=$1; shift; local replace=$1; shift
  in="$search" out="$replace" perl -pi -e 's/\Q$ENV{"in"}/$ENV{"out"}/g' "$@"
}
inplace_replace '@' "replacement" "$DIR/result/doc.md"
```

### The Longer Answer: Using `awk`

...or, using `awk` to do a streaming replacement, and a shell function to make that file replacement instead:

```
# usage as in: echo "in should instead be out" | gsub_literal "in" "out"
gsub_literal() {
  local search=$1 replace=$2
  awk -v s="${search//\\/\\\\}" -v r="${rep//\\/\\\\}" 'BEGIN {l=length(s)} {o="";while (i=index($0, s)) {o=o substr($0,1,i-1) r; $0=substr($0,i+l)} print o $0}'
}

# usage as in: inplace_replace "in" "out" /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 ...
inplace_replace() {
  local search=$1 replace=$2 retval=0; shift; shift
  for file; do
    tempfile=$(mktemp "$file.XXXXXX") || { retval |= $?; continue; }
    if gsub_literal "$search" "$replace" <"$file" >"$tempfile"; then
      mv -- "$tempfile" "$file" || (( retval |= $? ))
    else
      rm -f -- "$tempfile" || (( retval |= $? ))
    fi
  done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to add escapes to the slashes in the variable:

```sh
$ cat file
foo
bar
baz

$ set -- ' /repl'

$ sed "s/$/$1/" file
sed: 1: "s/$/ /repl/": bad flag in substitute command: 'r'

$ sed "s/$/${1//\//\\\/}/" file
foo /repl
bar /repl
baz /repl
```

That is a monstrosity of leaning toothpicks, but it serves to transform this:

```
sed "s/$/ /repl/"
```

into

```
sed "s/$/ \/repl/"
```

The same technique can be used for whatever you choose as the sed `s///` delimiter.